# What is the best way of hardcoding this data. Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I have an view in an app that is a help feature.

This view consists of textview and a tableview. The table view consists of a load of questions, when user selects a question it displays the answer in the `UITextView`.

What I'm trying to do is hardcode this data. Now i can get views to work nice and easy just code behind isn't the cleanest and with the questions and answers always changing, I want this data easily stored. What I'm thinking is a NSMutableArray something like this.

```
NSMutableArray *HelpPage = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: <answers,questions here>
```

how do I put say something like this in

```
NSMutableArray* HelpPage = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: 
@"How do i close", @"Press close button"
@"How do i open", @"Press the open button",
```

Btw I should add these are only examples lol.

ideally I'd like it in its separate .h/.m file so people can just send me updated versions and I don't have to spend ages merging stuff.

Is `NSMutableArray` best way of doing this?

in other areas of the app, i record users ethnicity, what i did here was

```
.h file
+ (NSArray*) ArrayofEthnicity;

.m file
+ (NSArray*) ArrayofEthnicity{
    return [NSArray arraywithObjects: @"English", @"French", @"German", nil];
}
```

and each time i need it calling

```
NSArray* Data = [EthnicityData ArrayofEthnicity];
```

is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: .c file with Objective-C?

Comment: @ElTomato I just proposed an edit for .c in .m file in the OP

Comment: add the help content into a plist ? Then grab it out as a dictionary ... ?

Comment: How about putting the data in database and pulling it only when needed?

Comment: it'll be called only in one popover and i think hardly used, atm theres about 20 questions and 20 answers but it being constantly changed as mood takes people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSMutableDictionary to store question and answer

```
NSMutableDictionary *qAndA = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
// add all Q&A with object is answer, key is question
[qAndA setObject:@"Press close button" forKey:@"How do i close"];
[qAndA setObject:@"Press the open button" forKey:@"How do i open"];
// to list all question
NSArray *questions = [qAndA allKeys];
.................................. 
// when need answer to a question
NSString *question = @"How do i close";
NSString *answer = [qAndA objectForKey:question];
```

Comment: is it possible to put nsmutabledictionary into its own seperate .h .m file like the nsarray example in question?

Answer (score 2):

It's depend how many time you have to use the questions and answers data and how many data you have to store.

If you have a lot of data to read a few times, you should write them into a `.plist` file.

If you have few questions and answer and you have to access them a lot of time in your app, then you can store them into an `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableDictionary` stored in an singleton instance to be able to access it from anywhere in the code.

An other solution is to use Core Data. It's more long to implement but it's the strongest way.

Core Data provide you to use an `SQLite` data base inside your app to store and read your data, but you can also use it to read your data from a remote web service.
One time again, this solution is the longest to implement but if you need a very optimized and very well designed solution, this is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be a property list file. (otherwise known as a .plist file)

Check the Apple Programming Guide for this...
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html

A quick example from the guide below. Essentially it's a good place to store parameters for your app.

**Listing 1-2**  Reading in and converting the XML property list

```
- (id) init {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSString *errorDesc = nil;
        NSPropertyListFormat format;
        NSString *plistPath;
        NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
           NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
            plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
        }
        NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
        NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
            propertyListFromData:plistXML
            mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
            format:&format
            errorDescription:&errorDesc];
        if (!temp) {
            NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
        }
        self.personName = [temp objectForKey:@"Name"];
        self.phoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:@"Phones"]];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

json is the most readable format AFAIK. Your JSON file will look like this

```
{
     "How do I close": "Press close",
     "How do I open": "Press open"
}
```

Or, in array format,

```
[
     "How do I close", "Press close",
     "How do I open", "Press open"
]
```

Loading would be a few lines of code with `NSJSONSerialization`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion `plist` is not the best way to store human readable text and `JSON` is not the most readable format. Especially if the maintainer of the files aren't developers, as I guess it's the case.

I'd rather write the help texts in **markdown**, with some fixed simple structure, like header + free text for each question. Or more elaborated with lists, links, whatever you need.

```
# Question 1

Answer 1 goes here.

# Question 2

Answer 2...
```

Then I'll write a parser to import the text into an internal format in order to show them to the user (an array of dictionaries or something similar).

You write this once, then just update the text files. The maintainer can use a markdown editor to validate the syntax.

Fortunately there are a [ton](https://github.com/dreamwieber/AttributedMarkdown) of [markdown](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/GHMarkdownParser) [parsers](https://github.com/mdiep/MMMarkdown) to hack this. I recommend [libsoldout](https://github.com/faelys/libsoldout), designed specifically to write custom parsers.

I wrote a [sample project to demo it](https://github.com/djromero/markdown_to_objc).